# jQuery-Tabledit throws MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: jquery, laravel, datatables, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to implement jQuery-Tabledit plugin to handle inline table fields editing. The problem is it's not sending data (passing parameters) to the controller and also it's throwing an error MethodNotAllowedHttpException "No message". I'm newbie in javascripts so please describe what I'm doing wrong.
Here's my code for controller (first of all I want to display parameters sent by script):

```
public function quantityUpdate(Request $request){    
        dd($request->all());
    }
```

Here's my route:

```
Route::post('quantityUpdate', ['as' => 'quantityUpdate', 'uses' => 'QuantityController@quantityUpdate']);
```

Script in View file:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.tabledit.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajaxSetup({
                headers: {
                    'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                }
            });
            $('#products_table').Tabledit({
                url: '{{route('quantityUpdate')}}',             
                columns: {
                    identifier: [0, 'id'],
                    editable: [[4, 'quantity']]
                },
                editButton: false,
                deleteButton: false,
                saveButton: false,
                restoreButton: false,
                onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                },
                onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                },
                onAjax: function(action, serialize) {

                    console.log("on Ajax");
                    console.log("action : ", action);
                    console.log("data : ", serialize);
                }
            });
        });
```

And my table:

```
<table class="table table-hover datatable" id="products_table">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($items as $item)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $item->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $item->name }}</td>
                            <td id="quantity">{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
```

Console output:

```
on Ajax
action :  edit
data :  id=5&quantity=111140&action=edit
ReferenceError: exception is not defined
```

Thank you for help! :)

Comment: What's your console output look like?

Comment: @Polaris I've eddited my post and added it :)

Comment: Change your route method to "get" -- "Route::get" and report back.

Comment: @Polaris I get an error 405, and in network console i see that script is sending data by post even though I've changed route to get :/

Comment: I've posted an answer I think may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Rewrite route to the following:

```
Route::post('/quantityUpdate', 'QuantityController@quantityUpdate');
```

In your view file script, change to the following:

```
$('#products_table').Tabledit({ 
url: '/quantityUpdate', 
columns: { 
identifier: [0, 'id'], 
editable: [[4, 'quantity']] 
}, 

onSuccess: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
console.log(data); 
}, 
onFail: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 

}, 
onAjax: function(action, serialize) { 

console.log("on Ajax"); 
console.log("action : ", action); 
console.log("data : ", serialize); 
} 
});
```

In your VerifyCsrfToken.php file:

```
protected $except = [
        '/quantityUpdate'
    ];
```

And finally, in your quantityUpdate controller, change the code to:

```
\Log::info($request->all());
```

and that should work.

Comment: `MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message` and also `None sent parameters` when I want to check xhr in network tab in dev tools.

Comment: What does the laravel log say for the $request->method() output?

Comment: Do you mean storage/logs/laravel.log . If yes `[2018-10-07 11:40:22] local.INFO: POST  
`

Comment: Yes, okay so it is using POST. I believe the error is because TableEdit is posting the info as JSON and not application/form-url-encoded. Open up VerifyCsrfToken.php and add "/quantityUpdate" to the $protected array. Then let me know if that fixes the MethodNotAllowedHttpException error. Then add this to the Controller and see if it outputs the JSON - dd(json_decode($request->getContent(), true));

Comment: I've edited my answer. I think this should work. I don't think the ajax is using the CSRF token and that's why the method not allowed exception is occurring. So we need to add the exception to the VerifyCsrfToken.php file

Comment: `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message` still :( I've added this exception.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181422/discussion-between-polaris-and-szeejdi).